# Inconsistent Logitech Mouse Clicks on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: mouse, logitech

I am having inconsistent clicks with my logitech m510 mouse with my new linux computer. Everything about the mouse works properly (tracking, scrolling) except the clicking action, which works intermittently.

- If I depress the mouse button for longer, it is more reliable.
- kernel version 6.1.0-1028-oem
- ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

What I have tried:

- I have dissasembled the mouse and cleaned it
- I have swapped the mouse to my old windows laptop and it works fine, pointing to Ubuntu
- I have tried disabling autosuspend in the kernel
- I have tried inspecting the mouse with Solaar, most options are greyed out for my mouse